# How to pass multiple values through one "get" in php?

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement push notifications for android. I want to send the same message to more than one phone from the server. For this I need to send through "get" more than just one registration key "regId". If you look at the bottom in the send_message.php I have `$regId = $_GET["regId"];` I just want to pass it more than just one value. How should I do this?

GCM.php

```
class GCM {

    // constructor
    function __construct() {

    }

 // Sending Push Notification
    public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {
    // include config
    include_once './config.php';

    // Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $message,
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
  }

  }

  ?>
```

send_message.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["regId"]) && isset($_GET["message"])) {
    $regId = $_GET["regId"];
    $message = $_GET["message"];

    include_once './GCM.php';

    $gcm = new GCM();

    $registatoin_ids = array($regId);
    $message = array("price" => $message);

    $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);

    echo $result;
}
?>
```

I just tried to test the demo app I have to see if I can send at two devices at once having the values hard coded and it still didn't work. I just want to see if it works first before I do it properly. From what I read about the google cloud messaging it should work to send to more than one device if you use HTTP. Anyone has an idea why it failed? It gives me "error":"InvalidRegistration". I guess there is nothing wrong with the php code but rather with the GCM. Here is what I tried:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET["message"])) {
    $regId = array("key1", "key2");
      $message = $_GET["message"];

    include_once './GCM.php';

    $gcm = new GCM();

    $registatoin_ids = array($regId);
    $message = array("price" => $message);

    $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);

    echo $result;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are passing a registration id using `$_GET`.

Thats not a good idea especially for multiple Ids.

I assume you want post data from your android app

You should do so using `$_POST`

I suggest you to encoded it in JSON array and send it to your server

You would create it from your app like this:

```
JSONArray regArray = new JSONArray();
regArray.put(regIds); //array of  Ids
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("message", message); //string
json.put("regIds", regArray);
```

This will create the following `JSON`

someting looking like the follwowing:

```
{   "message":"some message here",
    "regIds": [
        "dsdfsfet366767547",
        "63567356366reygh",
        "sgdgtwetwetsdgsdg",
        "sdgsdgsdgwet24t"
    ]
}
```

Comment: >I assume you want post data from you android app.


Yes that's what I want to do.
Ok, those look like good suggestions. I will try to do that, thank you. That should work.

Comment: Yes it is the only sane way to do this. GET is limited by the url length, registration ids are very long tokens you know